# How to animate this line graph

Tags: r, ggplot2, gganimate

I have this line graph I created this plot p using ggplot[image: Static Plot]

The code used to create the plot is below

```
p <- ggplot(teleco,aes(x = tenure, color = Churn))+ geom_freqpoly(size=2)+theme_minimal()
```

However I am wondering how best to animate it. I would like for the lines to fill in gradually. However I have tried this and it doesnt work as I believe I am not working with time.

```
p + transition_reveal(tenure)
```

When I run this code it comes through like so. What would be the best method to get it to animate to just have the lines fill in as they are in the static plot?

[image: Animated Plot]

Comment: It would be helpful to see the code used to create the plot as this seems to be where the issue is coming from. Even better, a minimal reproducible answer (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) will make it easier to help.

Comment: Thanks Tim I have added in the code used to create the plot now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess (it's hard to say for sure with a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)) is that the unwanted behaviour comes from using `geom_polygon`.

You could try instead manually grouping your data then using `geom_line`. Something like

```
teleco %>%
  group_by(tenure, Churn) %>%
  summarise(count = n(), .groups = 'drop') %>%
  ggplot(aes(tenure, count, col = Churn)) +
    geom_line(size = 2)
```

Comment: Thanks very much. This has solved it for me. Much appreciated Tim

Answer (score 1):

Here's a working, reproducible example of revealing the lines of a plot across the x axis. I would suggest trying `geom_line` instead of `geom_freqpoly` to get your example working.

```
library(datasets)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(gganimate)


aq <- datasets::airquality

ggplot(data = aq, aes(Day, Ozone, col = as.factor(Month))) +
  geom_line(size = 2) +
  transition_reveal(Day)
```